# to retrieve values from hashmap inside a hashmap

Tags: java

i have map,inside another map is there as a value

to retrieve values from hashmap inside a hashmap

```
map<string,map1<string,object>>
```

how to get or retrieve values from marks?

```
{
    "name": "mm",
    "language known": "English",
    "marks": {
        "english": [
            "88"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to get "88", or you want to get a collection containing "mm", "English", and the inner map?

Comment: `java`, that is not. `json`, that is.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried like this ,the marks map contains many keys of list values 

Map<String, Object> testmap = (Map<String, Object>) payload.get("marks");

params.setEnglish((List<String>) testmap.get("english"));
yes i want to get the value 88 and set to a pojo

Comment: params is a pojo class

Answer (score 1):

You can get inner map like this

```
Map<String, Object> innermap = outermap.get("marks");
```

Then use innermap to get value

```
String value=innermap.get("english");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what key corresponds to the inner map, you should first obtain the inner map:

```
Map<String, Object> innerMap = outerMap.get("marks");
```

Then you can get key-value pairs from the inner map using a for-each loop:

```
for (String key : innerMap.keySet()) {
    Object value = innerMap.get(key);
    // do something with key and value
}
```

Comment: from the inner map,i have to get value and set it pojo like setEnglish()